# Plotting a large number of data points in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a plot with a large number of data points using a VBA macro in excel. My understanding is that excel arrays won't work over about a certain number of entries, so I'm trying to plot it 500 points at a time.

My code (modified from a recorded macro) looks like this:

```
Do While ChartStart < rowmax
   ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Worksheets("DISPLAY").Range(Cells(ChartStart, 1), Cells(ChartStop, 4))
   ChartStart = ChartStart + 500
   ChartStop = ChartStop + 500
Loop
```

I get a 1004 (Object or Application Defined) Error when I run this. What's going wrong?

Comment: __replace__ `Worksheets("DISPLAY").Range(Cells(ChartStart, 1), Cells(ChartStop, 4))` __with__ `Worksheets("DISPLAY").Range(Worksheets("DISPLAY").Cells(ChartStart, 1), Worksheets("DISPLAY").Cells(ChartStop, 4))`

Comment: Possible issue -- your `Cells` inside the `Range` should be qualified. I'd suggest `Dim wsDisplay As Worksheet` then `Set wsDisplay = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DISPLAY")` then setting `Source:=wsDisplay.Range(wsDisplay.Cells(ChartStart, 1), wsDisplay.Cells(ChartStop, 4))`

Comment: If you're setting the chart data to a sheet range, then you should be able to use many more rows than 500: I just tried with 44k rows and it was OK with that...